# Append three regression tables into separate panels

Tags: latex, stata

Consider the following toy data:

```
input strL Country Population Median_Age Sex_Ratio GDP Trade year
"United States of America" 3999 55 1.01 5000 13.1 2012
"United States of America" 6789 43 1.03 7689 7.6 2013
"United States of America" 9654 39 1.00 7689 4.04 2014
"Afghanistan" 544 24 0.76 457 -0.73 2012
"Afghanistan" 720 19 0.90 465 -0.76 2013
"Afghanistan" 941 17 0.92 498 -0.81 2014
"China" 7546 44 1.01 2000 10.2 2012
"China" 10000 40 0.96 3400 14.3 2013
"China" 12000 38 0.90 5900  16.1 2014
"Canada" 7546 44 1.01 2000 1.2 2012
"Canada" 10000 40 0.96 3400 3.1 2013
"Canada" 12000 38 0.90 5900  8.5 2014
end
```

I run different regressions (using three different independent variables):

```
*reg1

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
qui reg `ii' Population i.year    
est table, b p
outreg2 Population using table, drop(i.year*) bdec(3) sdec(3) nocons tex(nopretty) append
}

*reg2

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
qui reg `ii' Median_Age i.year    
est table, b p
outreg2 Population using table2, drop(i.year*) bdec(3) sdec(3) nocons tex(nopretty) append
}

*reg3

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
qui reg `ii' Sex_Ratio i.year    
est table, b p
outreg2 Population using table3, drop(i.year*) bdec(3) sdec(3) nocons tex(nopretty) append
}
```

I use the `append` option to append different dependent variables that are to be regressed on the same set of independent variables. Hence, I obtain three different tables.

I wish to "merge" these tables when I compile in `LaTeX`, so that they appear as a single table, with three different panels, one below the other.

```
Table1
Table2
Table3
```

I can use the `tex(frag)` option of the *community-contributed* command `outreg2`, but that will not give me the desired outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing this, using the *community-contributed* command `esttab`:

```
clear

input strL Country Population Median_Age Sex_Ratio GDP Trade year
"United States of America" 3999 55 1.01 5000 13.1 2012
"United States of America" 6789 43 1.03 7689 7.6 2013
"United States of America" 9654 39 1.00 7689 4.04 2014
"Afghanistan" 544 24 0.76 457 -0.73 2012
"Afghanistan" 720 19 0.90 465 -0.76 2013
"Afghanistan" 941 17 0.92 498 -0.81 2014
"China" 7546 44 1.01 2000 10.2 2012
"China" 10000 40 0.96 3400 14.3 2013
"China" 12000 38 0.90 5900  16.1 2014
"Canada" 7546 44 1.01 2000 1.2 2012
"Canada" 10000 40 0.96 3400 3.1 2013
"Canada" 12000 38 0.90 5900  8.5 2014
end

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
    regress `ii' Population i.year 
    matrix I = e(b)
    matrix A = nullmat(A) \ I[1,1]
    local namesA `namesA' Population_`ii'
}

matrix rownames A = `namesA'

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
    regress `ii' Median_Age i.year 
    matrix I = e(b)
    matrix B = nullmat(B) \ I[1,1]
    local namesB `namesB' Median_Age_`ii'
}

matrix rownames B = `namesB'

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
    regress `ii' Sex_Ratio i.year 
    matrix I = e(b)
    matrix C = nullmat(C) \ I[1,1]
    local namesC `namesC' Sex_Ratio_`ii'
}

matrix rownames C = `namesC'

matrix D = A \ B \ C
```

Results:

```
esttab matrix(D), refcat(Population_GDP "Panel 1" ///
                         Median_Age_GDP "Panel 2" ///
                         Sex_Ratio_GDP "Panel 3", nolabel) ///
                         gaps noobs nomtitles ///
                         varwidth(20) ///
                         title(Table 1. Results)

Table 1. Results
---------------------------------
                               c1
---------------------------------
Panel 1                          

Population_GDP           .3741343

Population_Trade         .0009904

Panel 2                          

Median_Age_GDP           202.1038

Median_Age_Trade          .429315

Panel 3                          

Sex_Ratio_GDP            18165.85

Sex_Ratio_Trade            27.965
---------------------------------
```

Using the `tex` option:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Table 1. Results}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &          c1\\
\hline
Panel 1             &            \\
[1em]
Population\_GDP      &    .3741343\\
[1em]
Population\_Trade    &    .0009904\\
[1em]
Panel 2             &            \\
[1em]
Median\_Age\_GDP      &    202.1038\\
[1em]
Median\_Age\_Trade    &     .429315\\
[1em]
Panel 3             &            \\
[1em]
Sex\_Ratio\_GDP       &    18165.85\\
[1em]
Sex\_Ratio\_Trade     &      27.965\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**EDIT:**

This preserves the original format:

```
local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
    regress `ii' Population i.year 
    matrix I = e(b)
    matrix A = (nullmat(A) , I[1,1])
    local namesA `namesA' `ii'
}

matrix rownames A = Population
matrix colnames A = `namesA'

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
    regress `ii' Median_Age i.year 
    matrix I = e(b)
    matrix B = nullmat(B) , I[1,1]
    local namesB `namesB' `ii'
}

matrix rownames B = "Median Age"
matrix colnames B = `namesB'

local var "GDP Trade"
foreach ii of local var{
    regress `ii' Sex_Ratio i.year 
    matrix I = e(b)
    matrix C = nullmat(C) , I[1,1]
    local namesC `namesC' `ii'
}

matrix rownames C = "Sex Ratio"
matrix colnames C = `namesC'

matrix D = A \ B \ C
```

```
Table 1. Results
--------------------------------------
                      GDP        Trade
--------------------------------------
Population       .3741343     .0009904
Median Age       202.1038      .429315
Sex Ratio        18165.85       27.965
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: my original code had the dependent variables (GDP, Trade) listed as Col1 and Col2, and the independent variable (Population) as the row. I would like to maintain that format please